# How to initialize a range array of long-s in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, range, long-integer

A simple example of an array of longss

```
    long [] arrrray = {1, 2}; // it compiles
```

A simple example of int range array:

```
    int[] a = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).toArray(); // it compiles
```

But a simple example of range array of longs:

```
    long [] b = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).toArray(); // it does not compile
```

Is it possible and how to initialize an range array of longs?

Comment: Try reading your error message before posting on here - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to long[]

Comment: Use `LongStream` or `IntStream … asLongStream()`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try changing your `IntStream` into a `LongStream`:

```java
long[] b = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).toArray();
```

In fact, it won't compile with an `IntStream` since you are trying to put a `int[]` into a `long[]`

Answer (score 2):

How about using :

```java
long[] b = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).toArray();
```

As the way I see it,you are trying to use a IntStream to initalize a long array.

Answer (score 2):

**From Oracle Docs** :

> LongStream is a sequence of primitive long-valued elements supporting
>   sequential and parallel aggregate operations

```
long[] b = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).toArray();
```